# Map integers, that have the same population count (popcount), to continuous indexes (of an array)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation, associative-array

I would like to cache some values for repeated uses. In temporal accesses, these cached values can be identified by integers (keys) that have the same population count (popcount).

For example (popcount==2), the identifying integers are
`3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, ...`

For example (popcount==3), the identifying integers are
`7, 11, 13, 14, 19, 21, ...`

---

For O(1) time access of these cache values, I could simply use the identifying integer as an index to an array. However, it wastes a lot of storage space. For example, there are 5 integers (nCr, n=5,r=4) having 4 set bits (popcount=4) in the range [0,31]. Only 5 elements out of total 32 elements of an array are used in temporal access.

For efficient storage, I may consider using 'std::map<int, int>'. The time complexity should be O(log n).

---

I am looking for a solution that does not waste storage space and have good time complexity (e.g. O(1)). Hence I need a mapping function (mathematical formula) to map from the identifying integers to distinct elements a continuous array

For popcount == 2, the mapping function...

```
3 = 1+2 --> 0
5 = 1+4 --> 1
6 = 2+4 --> 2
9 = 1+8 --> 3
10 = 2+8 --> 4
12 = 4+8 --> 5
...
```

For popcount == 3, the mapping function...

```
7 = 1+2+4 --> 0
11 = 1+2+8 --> 1
13 = 1+4+8 --> 2
14 = 2+4+8 --> 3
19 = 1+2+16 --> 4
21 = 1+4+16 --> 5
...
```

Comment: A single array of 32 elements can map any integer in the range [0,31] to both its popcount, and its mapped value. The first few entries in that array would be `{(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), ...}` which says that `0` has popcount 0, and maps to 0 in its sequence, `1` has popcount 1, and maps to 0, `2` has popcount 1 and maps to 1, `3` has popcount 2 and maps to 0, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system